# Send email to admin user when custom post type is created

Tags: functions

I need to send an email to the admin user when a post of the post type "task" is created. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an email **on first publish and on updates**, you can avoid many extra checks by using {`status`}_{`post type`} action hook. Put the code below into the current theme's functions.php:

```
add_action( 'publish_task', 'wpse_admin_email', 10, 2 );
function wpse_admin_email( $post_id, $post ) {
    // prepare and send email code goes here...
}
```

If you want to send an email **on first publish only**, use the code below:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_admin_email_once', 10, 3 );
function wpse_admin_email_once( $new, $old, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'task' && $new == 'publish' && $old == 'auto-draft' ) {
        // prepare and send email code goes here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add action after wp insert post with specified post type:

```
    function after_task_post_created( $post_id ) {
    //no action if post type not task
    if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'task')
    return;
    // If this is a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

   // if post not yet published so no action taken, i know it can be confused
   if (get_post_status( $post_id ) != 'publish' )
   return;


    // your email action

        $yoursubject = 'This is your email subject';

        $yourmessage = "a body message here";

        // Send email.
    $adminemail = get_option( 'admin_email' );
        wp_mail( $adminemail, $yoursubject, $yourmessage );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'after_task_post_created');
```

reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/

Answer (score 1):

You could use this very easy action to control more than the creation of the custom post_type

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'transition_fun', 10, 3 );
function transition_fun( $new, $old, $post ) {
    if ( ( $new == 'publish' ) && ( $old != 'publish' || $old != 'auto-draft' ) && ( $post->post_type == 'task' ) ) {
        echo 'send mail......';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Just insert that to your **functions.php** or as a **plugin**.

If for example later you want to have access to the draft status you could easily do that with the 'auto-draft'

Comment: Your `if` statement includes wrong check for the post type. It should check for 'task', not for 'post'.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz Nice catch!